# Displaying an Image after uploading in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I have a question. So I found that you can upload an image in HTML and I used the following code:

```
<form name="imageUpload" method="post">
    <input type="file" multiple accept = image/* name="uploadField"/>
</form>
```

However, in light of using AngularJS, I was wondering if there was a way to, upon uploading the image, display the image in another location on the screen. If someone can point me in the right direciton, tha would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I just did exactly this in Angular, following [the answer to my similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015328/sending-an-image-to-the-server-after-displaying-it-in-the-ui-in-angular/21017082?noredirect=1#21017082). I'll share my code if it helps.

Answer (score 8):

It's more the javascript issue. As was answered here [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded). In angular it should look like this:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head >
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload Image</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('myApp', []).

        controller('UploadCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
            scope.image = "";
        }]).

        directive('myUpload', [function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        scope.image = e.target.result;
                        scope.$apply();
                    }

                    elem.on('change', function() {
                        reader.readAsDataURL(elem[0].files[0]);
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="UploadCtrl">
        <img ng-if="image" src="{{image}}" alt="">
        <form action="">
            <input my-upload type="file" name="upload">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like I through together: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LHUCdSmmXDLLZtFp6e30?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0" data-semver="1.2.0" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
    <canvas image-display file-data="{{data}},{{mimeType}},{{fileName}}"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```