# Sending an image to the server after displaying it in the UI in Angular

Tags: android, ios, json, image, angularjs

I'm getting an image upload, or from the camera in an Angular app:

```
<button type="button" onclick="userData.store()">send now</button><br>
<input type="file" label="add photo" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

Then (for now) handling it with this Javascript:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
var issuediv = document.getElementById('issue');

input.onchange = function () {
  var file = input.files[0];
  displayAsImage(file);
};

function displayAsImage(file) {
  var imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(file),
  img = document.createElement('img');
  img.onload = function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(imgURL);
  };
  img.src = imgURL;
  issuediv.appendChild(img);
}
```

Two issues:

1. This isn't Angular code—is what would be an Angular-ish way of handling the image and preparing it for the (MySQL) database via JSON?
2. The above displays the image blob in Firefox and Chrome, but iOS and Android browsers don't appear to append the `img` tag and display only a tiny thumbnail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Daniel Afarid's Angular File Upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)

Controller

```
$scope.selectedFiles = [];
$scope.dataUrls = [];
$scope.model = 'test model';

$scope.onImageSelect = function($files) {

    $scope.selectedFiles['image'] = $files[0];


    var $file = $files[0];
    if (window.FileReader && $file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsDataURL($files[0]);

        fileReader.onload = function(e) {
        $timeout(function() {
        $scope.dataUrls['image'] = e.target.result;
            });
        }
    }    

}

$scope.save_image =  function(){

        $upload.upload({
                  data:$scope.model,
                  url: 'the/url',
                  file: $scope.selectedFiles['image']

        }).then(//success and error callbacks);


    }
```

View

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="file" ng-file-select="onImageSelect($files)">
    <br />
    <img ng-show="dataUrls['image']" ng-src="{{dataUrls['image']}}">
    <button ng-click="save_image()"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, fine in Chrome, but what about when `window.FileReader` is undefined (e.g. Safari 5.1.10, or in IE9)? Angular File Upload seems to have fallbacks, but the implementation looks complex.

Comment: The other part of the question was how to prepare the image data as a sendable payload for database storage?

Comment: the window.FileReader is only used to capture the "to be uploaded" file and display to the user. You can still upload images without it

Comment: The image data is sent as formdata to the server
you can access it as you would any normal file upload from a browser