# How to display to the client an uploaded image?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, upload, angular-file-upload

I'm uploading an image using AngularJS to my NodeJS server. But I have no idea how to display the image back to the user. The upload works fine, I can see the image on the server, but then how do I get it back to the client side to display it?

HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{logo}}" class="col-sm-3" height="100" width="100">
    <div id="dropzone" ng-file-drop="" ng-file-select="" ng-model="files" class="drop-box col-sm-9" 
        drag-over-class="dragover" ng-multiple="false" allow-dir="false"
        accept=".jpg,.png"><b>Drop</b> image here or <b>click</b> to upload</div>
    <div ng-no-file-drop>File Drag/Drop is not supported for this browser</div>
```

JS: (angular using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) library)

```
$scope.upload = function (files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
                var file = files[i];
                $upload.upload({
                    url: "api/uploadLogo",
                    file: file
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("file " + config.file.name + " uploaded. Response: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                    $scope.logo = data;
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

In `data` in success, I get things like :
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? How am I supposed to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try handing back the location of the file and input it into a img tag like
    `<img ng-show="data['imgUrl']" ng-src="{{data['imgUrl']}}">`</s>

EDIT:
Searching StackOverflow came back with a similar question:
[Sending an image to the server after displaying it in the UI in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015328/sending-an-image-to-the-server-after-displaying-it-in-the-ui-in-angular).
Hope it helps.

EDIT 2:

Based on a better understanding of the requirements from the comments my suggestion is to use an image tag `<img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{logo}}" />` with a `$scope.image = data` in the controller.

This necessitates the return of a base64 encoded image file. Which would be done in node with `var base64image = new Buffer(imageFile).toString('base64')`. I use node here based on the tag of node.js but any language should be able to do base64 encoding.

Comment: The image is on the private part of the server, not public. This is because this images should not be seen by all users, but only by some in the same group. Will your solution work in this case ?

Comment: If the uploader has access to view the file it may work. Would a preview before uploading be what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I want to get back the image after the upload. As I would do if the user then reconnect : I'll have to get the image from the server again.

Comment: It looks like this is all handled by an API, so you could try `<img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}"  />` and `$scope.image = data`

Comment: If I'm going : `<img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{logo}}">`, the image URL looks like : `data:image/png;base64,img/noLogo.png` and I don't see anything =/

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that you will need to base64 encode the image before sending it back. It should be something like `var base64data = new Buffer(imagefile).toString('base64')` in node