# How to display a pic that I uploaded to my controller using my directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, image-uploading

Well, honestly this is my first attempt of working with pic upload in JS. I am working with an Angular project that needs to upload a pic from user and display it on a page. (Very much like we upload our profile pic on facebook, only difference being, this page will be downloaded as pdf later).

I was disappointed to see ng-model do not work with file type. I  tried many things and finally made a directive that brings file to my controller (got help from [here](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs)).

Now that I have file in my $scope.myPic variable. How do I go around using this file. How do I display it. 
. I tried binding the variable directly {{myPic}}, which didn't work
. I tried using (#id).value(). Storing this in variable and binding, which   didn't work.

There are other couples of thing I tried, but could not help myself out.

Can someone provide the way of binding image that are uploaded by users from their systems into HTML page in Angular.
Any good links are more than appreciated ...

FYI:

My directive fn:

```
function uploadPicFn($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.picModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
};
```

my html :

```
<div class="aw_textarea">
         <label>That's me:{{home.myPic}}</label></br>
         <input class="pd_txtarea" type="file" pic-model="home.myPic"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you upload your pictures somewhere?

Comment: Somewhere like ?? RIght now ,all I have is the pic file in my controller variable..

Comment: I think you can start here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986178/displaying-an-image-after-uploading-in-angular-js the issue sound similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, for example, with [File Reader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

You've mentioned that you got help from [here](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs). So I updated jsfiddle from that article with very basic code example of how FileReader can be used. Take a look - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1sdcxz7/)

```
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
          var modelSetter = model.assign;
          var img = element.parent().children()[2];
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
            angular.element(img).attr('src', e.target.result);
          }

          element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
            reader.readAsDataURL(element[0].files[0]);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Spot on !!!..Few question though. Firstly, Since I don't know much about File Reader. Can you explain what's happening here. Any link will be fine. Secondly, I see, you have written code for post request also. Since I don't really need that (as this page will directly be downloaded as PDF), I am assuming I can skip that part of your code?

Comment: Another curious question: Can I use this image like a normal variable (passing it between services and all..). Basically, how can I assign it to a scope variable so that I can use it in any img tag..in any page.  Kindly bear with me..Can't really check it right now as I do not have my code setup

Comment: yes, you can delete the fileUpload service if you don't need it. I just leave it because it was in the jsfiddle example from article.

Comment: because you have your image file in your $scope.myPic already, all you need to do is to call the FileReader in controller instead of a link function and save the result to some variable. Then, in any page that is under your scope, just write `<img src="{{FileReaderSavedData}}" alt="">`

Comment: Yup..that's sorted out..Only doubt i have now is how to bind this image at any other location. Say I want to upload it on one page and then keep it with me for a while and display it on another page..which is a different `state`

Comment: it is depend on your app structure. there are a lot of possible ways to move that image around. for example you can create a service and store the image file data in that service instead of controller. In this case, you can call the service with the image date from any controller in any scope.